# Anime where a girl sentenced to be killed is saved by a man who used to be little but grew quickly

Tags: story-identification, anime

I'm searching for the name of an anime I watched at least 10 years ago.

At the beginning, a girl is sentenced to be killed by her family or at least a group of persons who were sitting around a table.

The girl is saved by a man. I think he had red hair.

At some point the guy explain something weird, like he was little but grew into a man in a really short time. The sky was red or something as he explained.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SciFi.SE. Could you please take a look at [this checklist](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874) and [edit] in any extra details you remember?